# Why does Monopole in $D=3+1$ not drive a compact $U(1)$ gauge theory into a Confined Phase?

Tags: gauge-theory, topology, magnetic-monopoles, confinement

In compact $U(1)$ gauge theory, it has confined/deconfined phase. For $D=2+1$, monopole (2$\pi$-flux) event can always drive a system into a confined phase, as shown by duality mapping to a Sine-Gordon model. However, when I look at textbook written by Xiao-Gang Wen, Chapter 6, it says in $D=3+1$, you can get a deconfined phase. When he was stating that, he didn't mention about monopoles as if these are not important. Someone says monopoles in $D=3+1$ should be massive while it is massless in $D=2+1$ and that is the reason. However, I don't understand the difference between $D=2+1$ and $D=3+1$, and why in the $D=3+1$ case we can ignore monopole (or why there is a mass for monopole in this case)